# Why is the first section of transposed data copying over as unchangeable text?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been working on the conditional format settings on some transposed data in a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C6cPwtg0CZVfhjZm3KIxGJzcQaOfWCNXMWSKOei-zx0/edit?usp=sharing) I am building. I quickly discovered that the numbers in the first column of transposed data came up as text and no matter what I do to try and change it it stays as text. I need the data to copy over with its original formatting so that the number in head count is a number and then works with the conditional formatting.

This is the formula I used to transfer the data from one sheet to the other.

=TRANSPOSE(SORT(QUERY(Sheet1!A2:T985, "where E is not null and E = 'Catering' order by A", 1),4,FALSE))

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
=transpose(sort(filter(Sheet1!A2:T985,not(isblank(E2:E985))),1,1)
```

(Omitting `985` should also work. I do recommend giving it a try.)